# If you are in a terrain escape maneuver, would you be able to see traffic above you displayed in the cockpit of airliners

Tags: aircraft-performance, airliner, altimeter

nayed
If you are in a terrain escape maneuver, would you be able to see traffic above you in the cockpit of big airliners

Comment: What do you think a “terrain escape maneuver” is?  Why do you think (or not think) you’d be able to see traffic above you?

Comment: I down voted this question because you really haven’t explained what you mean by “traffic above you”. I think you also need to explain why you think a “terrain escape maneuver” is an important part of seeing  an aircraft above you.

Comment: (See chat -- https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61400721#61400721 and subsequent (may wrap to "next day"))

Comment: Well Yosef, can you help us help you by giving some context?  I assume from your other posts that you mean climbing at Vx in a light civil trainer, but what kind?  Or are you asking about military aircraft?  Because in a max G pull to the vertical you can definitely see above you.  There might be a good question in this, but you need to make it complete or you will get conflicting answers as you have here…

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you are in an aircraft with good upward visibility, and you tilt your head upwards, it is reasonable to presume that you could see traffic above you within your filed of view as you pitched up.

High wing aircraft generally don't have as good visibility in this direction as low wing aircraft, but a lot depends on the structure of the canopy and other possible obscurations to vision.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will not see aircraft above you. Very few aircraft have adequate visibility that would allow you to see other aircraft directly above. Fighter aircraft with a “bubble” canopy are one exception.

Comment: Directly above, and at zero pitch I agree.  But if you crane your head forward, pitch up and look around you can clear the space above to the extent that you ought to be able to avoid a collision.  (not saying it's a very good question though, because it obviously depends on the caveats I have given...)

Comment: I just added a “no” answer to counter your “yes” answer which sort of points out that it’s a poor question to begin with.

Comment: Yeah, good point...